# Could this model have soliton solutions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, spinors, solitons

We consider a theory described by the Lagrangian,

$$\mathcal{L}=i\bar{\Psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi-m\bar{\Psi}\Psi+\frac{1}{2}g(\bar{\Psi}\Psi)^2$$

The corresponding field equations are,
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m+g\bar{\Psi}\Psi)\Psi=0$$

Could this model have soliton solutions? Without the last term, it is just a Dirac field (if $g=0$), but it has to be included. This is similar to the [Thirring model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirring_model). I was looking for this field in books and papers but I haven't found it. If you know about it could you give me any reference?

Comment: I guess you are trying to make a Fermionic mexican hat. Please say so--- because either sign of m in the action gives a positive mass for the Fermion.

Comment: I guess m is positive as in dirac equation. What is the problem?

Comment: Oh--- ok--- I was wrong. I thought you were trying to make solitons like those that occur in the bosonic form of this action (which doesn't work).

Comment: Actually Im trying to know if some kind of soliton (or at least a solitary wave) is possible in this model.

Comment: @Anthony: this model is Fermionic. Solitons are coherent superpositions bosonic excitations. But the model conserves a U(1) charge which counts the Fermions, so that you can make a Fermi sea with a large numbers of fermions, and perhaps get a superconducting condensate, which can then have solitons. But I don't think this is what you meant. Perhaps you can say exactly what kind of soliton you are after? If you want a classical solution of the form $\psi(x)$, it's not going to work, because $\psi$ is Fermi.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is very important, but I'd want to know why you say that a classical solution is not going to work. I wonder if this model is known, as I say before I  I haven't found it in any reference and I would like to know if you have any.

Comment: @Anthony: Fermionic fields don't have classical solutions. This model is heavily studied--- it's the Gross Neveu model.

Comment: @Anthony: The solitons are for the fermion bilinears, and the relevant literature is Witten's "Nonabelian bosonization" of the late 1970s, 1978 or thereabouts. You are giving the 1 component model, which is "abelian bosonization" because it's a U(1) current algebra. U(1) can have solitons in 2d because the U(1) can wrap in a large circle in 2d, but the solitons are bosonic, they are like the BCS condensate solitons, not Fermions directly. I read these papers ages ago, but never worked with it, I'll try to write a proper answer, but it needs a little thought.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have never heard before that name, Gross-Neveu. If you can write an answer I will be very grateful.

Comment: @Anthonny, I have noticed you have not accepted any answers from your physics colleagues. Go through some old answers and accept some, as some of them, if not most, look well answered! :]

Comment: @RonMaimon: You should change your comment into an answer. We could vote it even if the OP does not close it.

Comment: @Jon: I would like to review Witten's article before doing so. I only get a chance to go to the library once a week, If you have institutional access, this is the nonabelian bosonization current algebra stuff.

Comment: But how do we know in general, just by looking at (any) Lagrangian, whether or not it will have soliton solutions? (sorry I joined late ... 2.5 yrs late ...)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is no assuming dimensions higher than 1+1. This can be seen observing that the equation of motion for the fermionic field is just the limit of mass going to infinity of a scalar field coupled to a fermionic field. This can be seen in the following way. Consider the Lagrangian
$$
    L = \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\bar\psi(i\gamma\cdot\partial-g\phi)\psi.
$$
The equations of motion are easily obtained to be
$$
   \partial^2\phi+m^2\phi=g\bar\psi\psi\qquad (i\gamma\cdot\partial-g\phi)\psi=0.
$$
The equation of the scalar field can be immediately integrated to give
$$
   \phi=g\int d^Dx\Delta(x-y)\bar\psi(y)\psi(y)
$$
with the propagator that of a free particle. This propagator, in the limit of a very large mass of the scalar field, is just proportional to $\delta^D(x-y)$. This observation is crucial for the following. So, we are left with the equation
$$
   (i\gamma\cdot\partial-\kappa\bar\psi\psi)\psi=0
$$
where $\kappa$ is a constant that depends on the parameters $m$ and $g$ of the Lagrangian we started from. In this way we have recovered the equation proposed by the OP but we have just proved that this is the large mass limit of a scalar field coupled to a fermion field.

Now, we do quantum field theory on the initial Lagrangian and write down the partition function as
$$
   Z[j,\bar\eta,\eta]=\int[d\phi][d\bar\psi][d\psi]e^{i\int d^Dx\left[\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\bar\psi(i\gamma\cdot\partial-g\phi)\psi\right]}
e^{i\int d^Dx\left[j\phi+\bar\eta\psi-\bar\psi\eta\right]}.
$$
The fermion part can be immediately integrated generating a potential to the scalar field in the form
$$
   V(\phi)=-i{\rm tr}\ {\rm ln}\left[i\gamma\cdot\partial-g\phi\right]_{(x,x)}.
$$
This can be evaluated by a loop expansion as
$$
   V(\phi)=-g_1\phi^3-g_2\phi^4+\ldots.
$$
Now, independently on the value of the mass of the scalar field and the presence of a finite v.e.v., using [**Derrick theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derrick%27s_theorem) *we know that stationary localized solutions to a nonlinear wave equation or nonlinear Klein-Gordon equation in dimensions three and higher are unstable.* This concludes the proof that the model equation yielded by the OP does not have soliton solutions in dimensions three and higher. In dimensions 1+1 these can exist.