# Is Thirring model a particular case of Gross model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, spinors

In the [Wikipedia entry for the Gross–Neveu model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Neveu_model), it is said that

> If one takes $N=1$ (which permits only one quartic interaction) and makes no attempt to [analytically continue the dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization), the model reduces to the massive [Thirring model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirring_model) (which is completely integrable).

But the aditional term in the Thirring model is
$$\frac{g}{2}\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi\right) \left(\overline{\psi}\gamma_\mu \psi\right).$$
I think this is different from $\frac{1}{2}g \left(\overline{\psi} \psi\right)^2$, the additional term of the Gross–Neveu model. So I think Wikipedia is wrong. Am I right?

If you do not mind, I would like that you respond to this question also: [Could this model have soliton solutions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16136/could-this-model-have-soliton-solutions)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the grassman expansion of a quartic fermi interaction can only be $\psi_1\psi_2\bar{\psi}_1\bar{\psi}_2$ in 2d, because there are only four grassman fields, so all other quartics are zero.

Comment: @James: Thanks, I should have fixed it--- it was a phone answer (no dollar signs available).